# uglyfy top level functions with gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp, uglifyjs

Take this simple gulp example for uglification:

```
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  // Minify and copy all JavaScript (except vendor scripts)
  return gulp.src(paths.scripts)
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(concat('all.min.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/js'));
});
```

If you have two files:

File `f1.js`:

```
function f1(){
  var hello = 1;
  return hello;
}
```

File `f2.js`:

```
function f2(){
  return f1();
}
```

The the result of the task in `all.min.js` is:

```
function f1(){var n=1;return n}
function f2(){return f1()}
```

How can I get uglify to mangle these top level function names i.e. `f1` and `f2`? I have tried:

**An extra uglify**

```
return gulp.src(paths.scripts)
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(concat('all.min.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/js'))
    .pipe(uglify());
```

**Passing mangle option**

```
return gulp.src(paths.scripts)
    .pipe(uglify({mangle: true}))
    .pipe(concat('all.min.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/js'));
```

**Passing top level option**

```
return gulp.src(paths.scripts)
    .pipe(uglify({toplevel: true}))
    .pipe(concat('all.min.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/js'));
```

But all to no effect at all.

Answer (score 6):

```
.pipe(uglify({mangle: {toplevel: true}}))
```

Answer (score 5):

It seems `uglify` will not mangle function names that are global variables (even with 'mangle' and `toplevel` parameters set to `true` at the same time). Doing this would seem quite impractical to me anyway, as any event handlers in your HTML wouldn't work after uglifying anymore and you couldn't (easily) invoke functions from the console either, as the name has probably changed.
If that is of no matter to you, try wrapping your code in a function scope:

```
(function(){
  // your code here...
}());
```

This way uglify will mangle the function names.

You could also try one of the `obfuscate` plugins for Gulp if it is about making your script inaccessible.

Comment: Thanks I'll give that a go tomorrow.